# How do I modify the automatically generated About window in my Cocoa app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

A menu item for "About MyApp" was automatically created for me and it displays an about window. How do I edit this window? I'd like to add some extra stuff there but I can't find the xib anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Use NSMenu and NSMenuItem for adding items. for editing default option open xib and edit MainMenu.

Comment: @Parag - I'd like to edit the actual about window though, not the mainmenu's menu items.

Answer (score 37):

Modify the contents of `Credits.rtf` file located inside the 'supporting files' group of your project.

[image]

Comment: what if I want to add some dynamic text? For example, I'd like to show whether the app is currently licensed or not. That's not something I can put in Credits.rtf

Comment: Make your own window controller and modify the target and action of the `About MyApp` menu button. Then if it gets clicked, create your window controller and show its window. That way you can have a custom `.xib` file for the window (or even load it programmatically). @simon.d

Comment: And BTW, this answer was really helpful. +1!

Comment: If I leave Credits.rtf, the window displays "[App Name] \n [Version number] ([Build number]) \n [Copyright]". However, for Safari it is "[App Name] \n **Version [Version number]** ([Build number]) \n [Copyright]". How do I add the string 'Version' before the version number?

Comment: @MichaelRobinson - sometimes?

Comment: If Credits.rtf doesn't exist, then create it and it will appear in About dialogue.

Comment: I made a demo project with @11684's suggestion (custom window controller, reads all data from plist, icon image from `NSApp`) : https://github.com/nicolas-miari/Cocoa-Custom-About-Window

Comment: @NicolasMiari you could add this as an alternative answer to make it more easily discoverable!

Comment: It's a bit of code to post inline, and link-only answers are no good (hence the comment). But I'll give it a try as soon as I'm on my desk.

Comment: @NicolasMiari no no i mean describe it a bit with a link or something just enough to make it clear what it does and why it is helpful etc

Comment: @MichaelRobinson Done, I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 19):

> A menu item for "About MyApp" was automatically created for me and it
>   displays an about window.

This is standard with Xcode templates for Cocoa apps. Keep reading to see how it is wired.

> How do I edit this window? I'd like to add some extra stuff there but
>   I can't find the xib anywhere.

There is no xib: This window is created at runtime by the application object (`[NSApplication sharedApplication]`), when it receives the message `orderFrontStandardAboutPanelWithOptions:`, which that menu item sends when selected (as you an verify in the Connections Inspector in Interface Builder).

By default (as others have mentioned), it loads the contents to display from a file named "Credits.rtf" if such file exists within your app bundle's resources; otherwise it grabs basic info from your app's Info.plist entries:

- App name
- Bundle version
- Copyright notice

What you can do is override this behaviour as follows:

1. Create a custom "About" window in Interface builder, with all the subviews and labels you want. Name the file "AboutWindow.xib".
2. Create a custom `NSWindowController` subclass, initialized with your custom window's nib name and set as the nib's owner:

   ```
   - (instancetype) init {
       if(self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"AboutWindow" owner:self]){
           // (other initialization...)
       }

       return self;
   }
   ```
3. Connect your About window's subviews to outlets in the window controller class.
   Also, specify the class for File Owner as your custom NSWindowController subclass and connect the window's "New Referencing Outlet" to File Owner's `window` property.
4. Go to MainMenu.xib in Interface Builder. Remove the action that is wired to the menu item "About ...", and re-wire a new one to the `about:` method of the placeholder object "First Responder".
5. In your app delegate, add an instance variable to hold your window controller so it does not get deallocated right away (alternatively, make your window controller class a singleton and use the shared instance):

   ```
   @implementation AppDelegate {

       AboutWindowController *_aboutwindowController;
   }
   ```
6. Still in AppDelegate, implement the method `about:` that you wired in step 3, like this:

   ```
   - (IBAction)about:(id)sender {
       if (_aboutwindowController == nil) {
           _aboutwindowController = [AboutWindowController new];
       }

       [_aboutwindowController.window orderFront:self];
   }
   ```

   ...or, if your view controller is implemented as a singleton, like this:

   ```
   - (IBAction)about:(id)sender {
       [[AboutWindowController defaultController].window orderFront:self];
   }
   ```
7. Finally, in order for your window controller to correctly display your app's information, read the relevant keys from the Info.plist file, like this (actual outlet ivars will be different in you case):

   ```
   - (void)windowDidLoad {
       [super windowDidLoad];

       // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window
       // controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.

       NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];

       self.appNameLabel.stringValue      = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleName"];    
       self.appVersionLabel.stringValue   = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
       self.appCopyrightLabel.stringValue = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"NSHumanReadableCopyright"];
   }
   ```

You might be tempted to read the app icon from the bundled resources too, but there's a more elegant way that works even if you didn't specify an icon and are stuck with the default "Ruler + Pencil + Brush over a Sheet" app icon: Grab the runtime icon image using the following code:

```
self.appIconImageView.image = [NSApp applicationIconImage];
```

I have put together [a demo project on Github](https://github.com/nicolas-miari/Cocoa-Custom-About-Window) that shows this and further customizations of the About window.

---

**UPDATE:** I have added a **Swift version** of the [demo project](https://github.com/nicolas-miari/Cocoa-Custom-About-Window) to the Github repository.

It features:

- Swift 4 (now that Xcode 9 is official)
- Storyboards instead of xibs
- Moved all the outlets to the new **view** controller, kept window appearance code in the **window** controller.

Comment: Is there any support for this in Swift 3?

Comment: It's in Objective-C; should be compatible with any version of Swift as long as your project has a bridging header. I'll make a Swift version at some time (no concrete plans yet)

Comment: Okay, shoot me a tag when you do! Thanks!

Comment: I've been able to recreate this for the most part in Swift. I'm stuck on one part though. How would I make the window show on main menu button press?

Comment: @dylan sorry for the delay (I hope you figured it out, though). You need to hook the menu item's action to the First Responder's `about:` method. For it to work ,the method needs to have a signature of `@IBOutlet func about(_ sender: Any)` in Swift **(Don't forget the underscore before the argument name!)**

Comment: Wonderfully complete answer. One query though - why not just implement the original "orderFrontStandardAboutPanelWithOptions:" in your AppDelegate, to open that window? why is the "about:" action needed?

Comment: @MottiShneor I wasn’t aware of that method